# video tag replays if drag thumb to end

Tags: html, html5-video

I use a videotag in my webpage.  If the user drags the thumb on the slider all the way to the right, I cover the videotag with a yellow div that has a message on it. (I catch the 'ended' event to do that).
This works well if the user drags the slider almost to the end and lets the video play the rest.
But, if the user drags the slider ALL the way to the right, the yellow screen does appear, but I can hear the soundtrack, and it shows that the video has re-started from the beginning, and is replaying from 0 seconds on.
Is this something I can do something about?

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same problem. Im looking for a better solution but this seems to work as dirty hack:

```
    var upFunc = function(){
        $(video).unbind('mouseup',upFunc);
        setTimeout(function(){video.pause();},1);
    };
    $(video).bind('mouseup',upFunc);
```

You have to bind to the mouseUp as that is what starts the replay off,rather than the ended event - hence why it doesnt happen when it finishes natrually. Then just for good measure you need to wait a milli second for the pause to actually work. If I find a better solution I will update this answer.